# vimのキーバインドのカスタマイズ

Tags: linux, vim

vimで矩形選択をする際に、`ctrl`+`v`でビジュアルブロックモードに変更してから実行するのは面倒なため、ノーマルモードのままで`ctrl`+`Alt`+`矢印キー`でvscodeのように矩形選択をしたいのですが.vimrcにどのような設定を追加すればよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

以下の設定でできると思います。
前半の4行は矩形選択を各矢印キーで開始するために必要です。
後半の4行は選択を開始した後にも `Ctrl` + `Alt` を押したまま矢印キーで 1 文字ずつ選択するために必要です。(ただし Vim 的にはすでに選択モードに入っているので修飾キーを押さなくても矢印キーだけで選択ができます。)

```
nnoremap <C-A-Right> <C-v><Right>
nnoremap <C-A-Left> <C-v><Left>
nnoremap <C-A-Up> <C-v><Up>
nnoremap <C-A-Down> <C-v><Down>
vnoremap <C-A-Right> <Right>
vnoremap <C-A-Left> <Left>
vnoremap <C-A-Up> <Up>
vnoremap <C-A-Down> <Down>
```